# Failed to add platform android - cordova

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-3, platform

I am trying to setup new cordova and ionic project. When i ran this command,

```
corodva platform add android
```

I am getting this error

[image]
What would be the issue?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? This seems to indicate that your computer can't reach the npm repository where `cordova-android` is hosted. You might try adding the git repo, but be aware that it is bleeding-edge.

Comment: Not sure i am behind proxy..  have no idea. while installing i'am getting this error.